# How do I do python unittest doc's recommended method of lazy import?

Tags: python, python-import

Python's docs say that there's an alternative to local imports to prevent loading the module on startup:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-imports-with-patch-dict

> ...to prevent “up front costs” by delaying the import.
>   This can also be solved in better ways than an unconditional local
>   import (store the module as a class or module attribute and only do
>   the import on first use).

I don't understand the explanation in brackets. How do I do this? However I think about it, I seem to end up with local imports anyway.

Comment: It's not very clearly written. Maybe the sentence in parenthesis is an example of an "unconditional local import", and not an example of the opposite?

Comment: @HåkenLid In the previous part of the paragraph, it states "They are sometimes done to prevent circular dependencies, for which there is usually a much better way to solve the problem (refactor the code)". So I'd assume the brackets mean the solution.

Comment: What this likely refers to is the use of `import` through `importlib` as described in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation likely refers to the use of [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module), which exposes Python's `import` functionality:

```
import importlib

class Example():

    TO_IMPORT = "os"  # the name of the module to lazily import
    __module = None

    def __init__(self):
        if self.__module is None:
            self.__module = importlib.import_module(self.TO_IMPORT)
```

Note that this way the module is only imported once when the class is first instantiated and is not available in global namespace.

Further, it allows you to change which module is imported, which could be useful e.g. in cases where the same class is used as an interface to different backends:

```
import importlib

class Example():

    def __init__(self, backend="some_module"):
        self.module = importlib.import_module(backend)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is better? This seems to be no different from a unconditional local import other than that it uses the `import_module` function
e.g. why not
`def __init__(self):    import os    self.module = os`? (sadly, I can't create line breaks in comments, but I hope you get my point)

Comment: The difference is that `import os` imports into the global namespace and will import the module every time the class is instantiated. I edited the example so that the import only happens once.

Comment: Sorry for taking awhile to respond, I think I can see what your first example does. However, I think the use of importlib is a red herring. Generally, delayed-import doesn't need dynamic-import behavior.

Comment: What makes you believe that using `importlib` is a red herring?

Comment: I can do the exact same thing with `import os` in the function. The only purpose of importlib is to allow dynamic import (the ability to change what you import in code). The purpose of lazy import is to delay the import so startup does not have the cost of importing. It's actually different purposes

Comment: I would like to disagree that dynamic imports are the only purpose of `importlib`. The documentation contains plenty of hints what the module can be used for and why it is included in Python. In your question, you asked for clarification of the sentence you quoted, and I've provided you with an example of what I believe the original authors meant. They clearly state why using `importlib` is beneficial for unittesting. If you don't agree with them, you're free to continue using `import` statements.

Comment: Hold on, where did they specifically state importlib is beneficial for unittesting? I ctrl-f for "unit" in the importlib docs and see nothing, and ctrl-f for "importlib" in unittest docs and also see nothing.

Comment: From the documentation you linked: [One situation where mocking can be hard is where you have a local import inside a function. These are harder to mock because they aren’t using an object from the module namespace that we can patch out.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-imports-with-patch-dict)

Comment: ...and what does that have to do with importlib specifically? Are you implying to patch importlib?

Comment: You asked what the authors of the unittest documentation meant, and I explained to you what they presumably meant: If you store the module as a class attribute, it is easy to replace ("patch out") the module with a mock at test time. They argue that it's much harder if the module is in the global namespace, and go on to provide a solution for that as well.

Comment: Well, I guess I don't understand is why they'd presumably mean using importlib. I'm trying to understand the connection you have, but I don't get it. Why not this? https://trinket.io/python/0d537bcbbd

Comment: That you can do, but you cannot "patch" that import prior to creating the instance (if the name of the module is stored as a class parameter, you can, never importing the "original" module at test time) and it possibly interferes with the module's/global namespace. If that's fine for your application, I don't see anything wrong with doing it that way, though.